# Issue when sending http requests to android emulated devive

Tags: android, mobile, automated-tests, adb

I m trying to run some ui automated tests on a android virtual device( android studio) and I have the bellow issue:

After my app is installed on the device , from my framework I sending http request to some endpoints which are exposed by my client( mobile app) but seems like the requests are not reaching the client.

Any advise?

thank you !

Comment: If I connect a real device via USB there is no issue when trying to make the requests.

Comment: What IP do you use for the emulated device (because Android emulator does not assign any accessible IP to an emulated device)? So by default from host PC no port is accessible so there is no way to access a service via IP. You ned to redirect ports from emulator to host PC: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: 10.0.2.15 is the ip of the emulated device

Comment: That is the internal fixed IP, every emulated device uses that IP but that IP is not accessible from outside, there is not IP routing from host to guest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to enable this routing?

Comment: Please read my comment Android emultaor only supports port redirecting for accessing services on device. Otherwise you need an emulator which supported routing like VirtualBox based emulators (e.g. Genymotion).

Comment: Thank you! Installed genymotion and i Still get the same error, should do extra steps?

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect the port (or ports) used via `adb`.
If you want the same port on local and remote you could do:

```
port=1234; adb forward tcp:$port tcp:$port
```

otherwise, specify different port.

Then, any request to your local port will be forwarded to the remote.

Comment: maybe stupid question, but how can I see which ports to fwd? thx

Comment: you created the endpoint so you should know

Comment: if you don't know, just run `adb shell netstat -nat` and check the `LISTEN`ing ports

Comment: I forwarded the 8195 port but now I get this error : 192.168.1.170.0.0.0 nodename nor servername provided or not know

Comment: runing the adb command to see the ports : local adress 0.0.0.0:8195 foreign adress 0.0.0.0:* listen

Comment: Then you confirmed that port 8195 is listening for tcp connections. If you forward the port correctly you'll be able to connect.